# How can I make my code shorter for a simple maze game?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Good Day. I'm a beginner in coding, and basically I made a simple maze game using python. 
it's 3x3 so I made 9 dictionary variables that detailed the possible movement for each tile (North, south, east, west.) 
my code consists of nested if-elif as well as a main while loop.

```
if level == 1: #level of difficulty.
    i = 0
    maplist1 = {'directions1':'south'}
    maplist2 = {'directions1':'south','directions2':'east'}
    maplist3 = {'directions1':'west'}
    maplist4 = {'directions1':'north','directions2':'east','directions3':'south'}
....
....
    current_position = 1 #local variable within the first if statement
```

Here's a snippet of the code block that would be repeated, with little to no variations (literally repeating) to it.

```
    while i == 0: #to continuously loop the program
        if current_position == 1:
            directions = maplist1['directions1']
            direction = input(f"What direction do you want to go: {directions} ").title() #choose the possible directions to go to.
            if direction == "S" or direction == "South":
                current_position = 4
                print(f"You are in cell {current_position}.")
            else:
                print("Cannot go in that direction.")
        if current_position == 2:
            directions = maplist2['directions1']
            directions2 = maplist2['directions2']
            direction = input(f"What direction do you want to go: {directions} {directions2} ").title()
            if direction == "S" or direction == "South":
                current_position = 5
                print(f"You are in cell {current_position}.")
            elif direction == "E" or direction == "East":
                current_position = 3
                print(f"You are in cell {current_position}.")
            else:
                print("Cannot go in that direction.")
        if current_position == 3:
            directions = maplist3['directions1']
            direction = input(f"What direction do you want to go: {directions} ").title()
            if direction == "W" or direction == "West":
                current_position = 2
                print(f"You are in cell {current_position}.")
            else:
                print("Cannot go in that direction.")
        if current_position == 4:
            directions = maplist4['directions1']
            directions2 = maplist4['directions2']
            directions3 = maplist4['directions3']
            direction = input(f"What direction do you want to go: {directions} {directions2} {directions3} ").title()
            if direction == "N" or direction == "North":
                current_position = 1
                print(f"You are in cell {current_position}.")
            elif direction == "S" or direction == "South":
                current_position = 7
                print(f"You are in cell {current_position}.")
            elif direction == "E" or direction == "East":
                current_position = 5
                print(f"You are in cell {current_position}.")
            else:
                print("Cannot go in that direction.")
.......
......
.......
        if current_position == 9:
            print("Congratulations, you finished the game.")
            i += 1 #to stop the loop
```

my question is how to make this simpler, and more compact?

- Current location must be remembered every movement
- I know how to use def but quite unsure on how to implement it in my maze game.

There are 3 levels to this game, basically 3x3, 4x4, and 5x5. that's the reason why I am asking for any ideas on how to shorten/compact the code.

I don't need you to give me your code, but some guidance would be great on how to proceed because i am feeling lost right now.

Comment: 1. Use data structures. (Lists, dictionaries.) 2. Extract methods.

Comment: Also, this question might be better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a maze data structure. One typical idea is to create a 2D array of cells, each with a north/west/south/east wall.

Let's create a class, just for better understanding. I want you to **ignore everything except the `can_move()` method**.

```
class Cell:
    def __init__(self, walls):
        self.walls = walls

    def __str__(self):
        """Allows us to call print() on a Cell!"""
        return '\n'.join(self.draw())

    def _draw_wall(self, wall, s):
        return s if wall in self.walls else ' ' * len(s)

    def draw(self, inner='   '):
        """Draw top, mid, and bottom parts of the cell."""
        n = self._draw_wall('N', '___')
        w = self._draw_wall('W', '|')
        e = self._draw_wall('E', '|')
        s = self._draw_wall('S', '___')
        top = ' ' + n + ' '
        mid = w + inner + e
        bot = w + s + e
        return top, mid, bot

    def can_move(self, direction):
        return direction not in self.walls
```

Let's make some cells and see what they look like:

```
>>> Cell('NWSE')
 ___ 
|   |
|___|

>>> Cell('NWS')
 ___ 
|    
|___
```

Now, a maze is made out of a 2D list of cells. Here's a small maze:

```
maze = Maze(width=3, height=3, rows=[
    [Cell('NWE'),  Cell('NW'),   Cell('NE')],
    [Cell('WE'),   Cell('WE'),   Cell('WE')],
    [Cell('WS'),   Cell('SE'),   Cell('WSE')]
])
```

Which looks like this:

```
>>> maze
 ___  ___  ___
| x ||        |
|   ||        |

|   ||   ||   |
|   ||   ||   |

|        ||   |
|___  ___||___|
```

But wait! We haven't defined what `Maze` is. Once again, **ignore all the drawing related stuff and focus on `move_direction()`**.

```
class Maze:
    def __init__(self, width, height, rows):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.rows = rows
        self.position = (0, 0)

    def __str__(self):
        return '\n'.join(self.draw_row(i) for i, _ in enumerate(self.rows))

    def _inner(self, i, j):
        return ' x ' if (i, j) == self.position else '   '

    def draw_row(self, i):
        triples = [
            cell.draw(self._inner(i, j)) for j, cell in enumerate(self.rows[i])
        ]
        return '\n'.join([
            ''.join(t for t, _, _ in triples),
            ''.join(m for _, m, _ in triples),
            ''.join(b for _, _, b in triples)])

    def cell_at_position(self, i, j):
        return self.rows[i][j]

    def move_direction(self, direction):
        curr_cell = self.cell_at_position(*self.position)
        if not curr_cell.can_move(direction):
            print("Can't go in that direction!")
            return
        deltas = {'N': (-1, 0), 'W': (0, -1), 'S': (1, 0), 'E': (0, 1)}
        y, x = self.position
        dy, dx = deltas[direction]
        self.position = y + dy, x + dx
```

To use this, just create a simple small loop:

```
while True:
    print(maze)
    direction = input('What direction? ')
    maze.move_direction(direction)
```

And watch the magic happen!

You can try it [here](https://repl.it/@SicariusNoctis/SO-Maze).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of thinking the maze in 1D i.e the current_position(1,2,3..,9), you should think and code it like a 2D matrix space((0,0),(0,1)).

And Instead of hard coding the base maze to 3, we should be thinking in terms of n x n maze, as now that you have implemented the logic for a 3 x 3, now you should be able to expand it to n x n.

And you handled the possible directions using your maps instead, we should write the logic for boundary conditions, like a method to check the directions possible on each step,

```
def possible_path(current_x, current_y, matrix_size=3):
    # this returns like directions possible like current_x + 1 < matrix_size
    # then the east direction is possible.
   pass
```

Direction handling should be handled somewhat like this,

```
 def position_handler(row, col, direction):
     # can write the logic for mapping the direction to the movement in X and Y,
     # if direction == 'NORTH' 
     # or can get the config from a map like,
     # move = movement.get(direction)
     # say NORTH config is =>movement= {'NORTH': {'x': 0, 'y':1}}
     # and now move accordingly i.e 
     # row += move.get('x')
     # col += move.get('y')
     pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Exploit rules instead of hardcoding anything.

If you have a 3x3 maze, your (x,y) indexes are somthing like

```
0,0   1,0    2,0
0,1   1,1    2,1
0,2   1,2    2,2
```

You can store this as list of lists:

```
field = [ ["one","two","three"],["four","five","six"],["seven","eight","nine"] ]
pos = (0,0)
p = field[pos[0]][pos[1]] #  would be "one"

# rules for movement based on actual position:
move_right = pos[0] < (3-1)
move_left = pos[0] > 0
move_up = pos[1] > 0
move_down = pos[1] < (3-1)
```

You can use functions to code this:

```
# p is a coordinate (0,0) etc tuple of x and y

# as functions
def can_move_right(p, dim=3):
    return p[0] < dim-1

def can_move_left(p,dim=3):
    return p[0] > 0

def can_move_up(p, dim=3):
    return p[1] > 0

def can_move_down(p,dim=3):
    return p[1] < dim-1

def move_up(p):
    if can_move_up(p):
        return (p[0],p[1]-1)
    # implicitly returns None if not possible

def move_down(p):
    if can_move_down(p):
        return (p[0],p[1]+1)

# etc

new_pos = move_up( (1,1) )  # => (1,0)
new_pos = move_down( (1,1) )  # => (1,2)

new_pos = move_up( (0,0) )  # None - need to handle it
if not new_pos:
    print("Wrong move")
```

To adjust for `n` x `n` you just need to give other `dim` - the rules are the same.